# Creating a sequence starting with 0

Tags: r, seq

I like to use the `seq()` command in R to create a sequence starting at zero. but when I type e.g.

```
seq(0:14)
```

I get the following output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 36):

As others have said you want `0:14` or `seq(from=0,to=14)` The reason you get your undesired result is also worth noting.

In this case, the colon operator on its own (as described in `?':'`) is generating the desired regular sequence of integers, which you are then supplying to `seq()`.

`seq()` is guessing that you mean `seq(along.with = 0:14)` which returns a sequence of the same length as the thing you supplied. And of course it is using the default `from = 1`.  So it gives you a sequence of fifteen integers starting at one. It's roughly analogous to this:

```
(x <- 0:14)
# [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14

seq(along.with = x, from = 1)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Despite causing the error you got, this `along.with` functionality is clearly useful for making sequences that are the same length as some vector/list/matrix:

```
seq(c(1,"w",5,6,NA))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

And we can't say `?seq` didn't warn us about naming our arguments:

> The interpretation of the unnamed arguments of seq and seq.int is not
>   standard, and it is recommended always to name the arguments when
>   programming.

Answer (score 14):

You mean to do

```
0:14
```

or

```
seq(0, 14)
```

Answer (score 3):

`seq(0, 14)` got following input for me:

```
[1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem here is with syntax. i:j creates a sequence from the number i to j; for example 1:5 can be read as 1 to 5 or 1,2,3,4,5.

On the other hand, the function seq takes a 'to' parameter, and a 'from' parameter, both of which must be single numbers. Entering seq(0:14) means that a vector - not a single number - is handed to one of seq's parameters.

What you want is

```
seq(from=0, to=14)
```

Hope that helps