# Plot function with the number one and colon

Tags: r, plot

What does the 1 and colon mean in this plot function?

```
plot(1:length(yeast),yeast,xlab="time(h)",ylab="mass yeast(g)")
```

I tried searching it on Google but mostly found `plot()` , explanation of the types of plots and the different plot functions in R. But nothing about my above question.

Comment: it's short for `seq(1, length(yeast), 1)`

Comment: @rawr, post as answer?  (@Peace, you could try (could have tried) https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+the+colon+operator+in+R ...)

Comment: In this instance, the `:` denotes _from_ 1 _to_ the length of your yeast object. For instance, run this `vector <- 1:10` and then if you run `length(vector)` it will return 10 because 'vector' is 10 values long. So running `1:length(vector)` is synonymous with `1:10`.

Comment: R itself has great help built-in with the `?` operator. For instance, if you typed in `?:` (that's question-mark and colon), you should see something akin to https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Colon.html.

Comment: Possible duplicate (enough info here to answer the question at least) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082159/creating-a-sequence-starting-with-0/14083167#14083167